# Is the "The Pirate King" another structure of "The King of Pirates", interchangeably or "Pirate" is like an adj., meaning "The King that is a pirate"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, ambiguity, semantics, compounds

I have ambiguity with the meaning of some **compound nouns**, especially in the form **noun+noun** like: **"The Pirate King"**, **"The Lion King"**, **"The Pirate Bay"** and so on.

## EDITED:

to put it **in context**:

> Consider this famous movie title: **"The Lion King"**, is it literally *another structure* of **"The King of Lions"**, meaning are they **interchangeable** like **<< the owner of the restaurant = the restaurant owner >>**?
>
>  Or: **"Lion"** is a noun but like an adjective describing the kind or type of the **"King"**, meaning literally **"the King (of the Jungle) that is a lion"**?
>
>  If the latter, then doesn't **"The Pirate Bay"** mean **"the Bay of Pirates"**?
>
> > Also consider what ***Luffy*** said in **"One Piece"**:
> >
> > > I'm Monkey D. Luffy, the man who will become the **Pirate King**!

Comment: Actually, The Pirate King more closely transposes to The King of *the* Pirates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [strings of nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_string) in English it is virtually impossible to deduce the exact meaning purely from grammar, and it usually has to be inferred from context. In terms of pure grammar, both interpretations are possible.

For example most people reading "a pirate king" or "a fairy king" would assume it meant the king of the pirates, or the king of the fairies, but this is based on contextual knowledge that pirates and fairies sometimes have kings over them (at least they do in fiction - and of course the pirate king or the fairy king are normally pirates or fairies).

But for other nouns the reverse would be assumed. A "philosopher king" or a "warrior king" would be assumed to be a philosopher, or a warrior, who was also a king. They would not necessarily be king over other philosophers or warriors. This is again based on contextual expectations that philosophers or warriors don't usually have their own kings. This could be subverted - for example in a story where philosophers had formed their own nation it might be expected that the philosopher king was king over all philosophers.

If there is danger of confusion you can write "king of the pirates" or "the king who was a pirate", but if you are reading the phrase on its own you will have to look for contextual clues.

Comment: I basically agree except this is not about strings of nouns. Only two nouns, right? Anyway, +1 for simplicity and understandable language.

Comment: @Lambie 'String' is a blanket term for any number of words appearing in sequence in writing, print, code.... DJC correctly points out that a N + N string does not automatically qualify as a compound noun. It could alternatively be a close collocation, a loose collocation, or a nonce juxtaposing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_string

Comment: @Lambie I'm going to steal that link.

Comment: Please, be my guest. :)

Comment: @Lambie: [Farlex:  linguistic string](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/linguistic+string) ... Noun 1. linguistic string - a linear sequence of words as spoken or written ... string of words, word string
 ... string - a linear sequence of symbols (characters or words or phrases) // also  'We used the CQP query syntax to extract all strings of two nouns that followed....' [[Modelling Semantic Transparency_Bell & Schäfer](https://arro.anglia.ac.uk/702948/1/Bell_2016.pdf)]

Comment: @Lambie - That's a great link -- thanks for posting that.  But I don't see where it says that a noun string has to have more than two nouns, or that a noun string is necessarily a *long* noun string.  I took DJClayworth to mean *some nouns strung together*.

Comment: Here, the issue is ambiguity in titles due to noun, possessive, adjective issues, not strings like: Draft laboratory animal rights protection regulations [found online]. I personally would not call The Lion King issue a string. But people can do as they please. I like the explanation in this answer, I just do not like the term noun string here to describe the issues involved in titles as given here.

Comment: @Lambie - Okay, let's call it a tomato-tomahto thing.  I agree, I like the answer too.

Comment: @Lambie - ¿Una vez más, con *feeling*, por favor?

Comment: @aparente001 Sorry, I thought you were Brazilian.

Comment: @Lambie - https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/9385

Comment: @DJClayworth  First, thanks for your answer, but if it grammatically can mean "king of the lions" and "king of the pirates", why it's written "the lion king" and "the pirate king" instead of "the lions king" and "the pirates king".